# Insert procedure in mysql with condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to create a procedure for inserting a row with some condition. Am new for this field please any one help me to do this.

My Table structure is.

```
Id startDate enddate    transdate   status.
1  1/12/2012 30/12/2012 31/12/2013  CLOSED
2  1/1/2013  30/1/2013  31/1/2013   OPEN
```

My Query logic is here.

This procedure is run every day.But the procedure check the last entry that is  id=2 and check the transaction date. if the transaction date less than the current date means.update the last record status as CLOSED and insert the new record automatically with the below last Record.

```
Id startDate enddate    transdate   status.
1  1/12/2012 30/12/2012 31/12/2013  CLOSED
2  1/1/2013  30/1/2013  31/1/2013   CLOSED
2  1/2/2013  27/2/2013  28/2/2013   OPEN
```

Any one help me to do this.

Comment: Before you do anything - change your 'date' fields to mysql 'date' type. It will make this process much easier.

Comment: K i change the date field now. Can you help me to do this.

Comment: Is 'id = 2' special or is it just some entry? Why is 'id = 1' marked as 'closed'?

Comment: If the record cross the transaction date means that status change to closed.

Comment: Create every transaction period for every month.

Comment: so if 'transdate' is later than the current date you want to mark it as 'closed' and insert a new record? What goes in the new record?

Comment: yes the i need the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be something like this:

```
create procedure updatetable()   
BEGIN
    declare found_id as int;
    select id into found_id from table where transdate >= curdate() and status = 'open';
    if (!is_null( found_id )) THEN
       update table set status = 'closed' where id = found_id;
       insert into table( startdate, enddate, transdate, status ) 
           values concat( year(curdate()), "-01-", month(curdate())), 
                  concat( year(curdate()), "-", LAST_DAY( curdate()), month(curdate())), curdate(),
                  "open" );
    END IF

END
```

You'll need to debug this a bit as I'm just guessing the syntax. The intent is to check for any entries with transdate equal to or after the current date. If any are found then update that entry to be 'closed' and create a new entry with the first and last date of this month and status = 'open'.